# at25 spi eeprom device tree

Tags: device, spi, eeprom

newb here. I have installed the at25 eeprom driver as a kernel module, but need a pointer to creating a device tree entry. I have a loaded and tested an SPI device tree overlay. Any help appreciated. TIA

Comment: some specific question?

Comment: Yes - I have a working SPI device (beaglebone black, debian 4.1.6...) that I've tested with spidev_test. I have installed the "standard" at25-type eeprom LKM, and would like to use that. As I said, I'm a newb at this - what am I missing between these so that I may read/write to the eeprom? I am guessing that I need to install the eeprom as a device, but am at a loss to where to start.